# Correct way of converting unicode to emoji

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, emoji

I'm using `String.formCodePoint` to convert Unicode to emoji, but some emojis don't convert as expected. They display like line icons. Please check the example below, first two emojis render correctly, but the last two don't.

for example:

```js
const unicode = ["1f976", "1f97a", "263a-fe0f", "2639"]


unicode.forEach((val) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(val, 16))
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Probably the problem is the font. And your third emoji: are you sure you are constructing the right code? ParseInt will give you just the first value, without the variation selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct.

Old Emoji are not coloured by default, so you need to add the variation code 'fe0f`. You tried on the third one (but not on the forth one), but you convert wrongly to numbers, so it will fail.

This code will fix it (if you have emoji fonts installed).

```js
const unicode = ["1f976", "1f97a", "263a", "fe0f", "2639", "fe0f"]


unicode.forEach((val) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(val, 16))
});
```